# transactions and Oracle dblink

Tags: oracle-11g-r2, transaction, dblink

I have 2 dbs, let's call them writedb and readdb.  Readdb has a dblink to writedb and a view to a table over that dblink.

I do an update on writedb to that table which view points to and then read from that table over the dblink.  I appear to be seeing old values for seconds after the transaction commits even if I set isolation level to SERIALIZABLE.
Does this make any sense?

On writedb:

```
create table mk.dblink_test (
id varchar2(16),
status varchar2(16));

insert into mk.dblink_test
SELECT rownum, 'ACTIVE'
FROM   dual
CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 1000000;
```

On readdb:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK DBL_TEST CONNECT TO mk IDENTIFIED BY password USING 'writedb:1521/qa'
```

The SQL that updates writedb directly:

```
update mk.dblink_test
set status = 'DONE'
where id = '1';
commit;
```

Now the situation with SQL which get dirty reads is weird.  The following simpler query

```
SELECT r.status
FROM mk.dblink_test@DBL_TEST r
WHERE r.id = '1';
commit;
```

does not appear to exhibit the problem.
But a more complex version:

```
SELECT r.status
FROM mk.dblink_test@DBL_TEST r
LEFT OUTER JOIN (SELECT '3' status from dual) optout ON optout.status = r.status
WHERE r.id = '1';
commit;
```

reproduces it 90% reliably.
The steps to reproduce:

1. launch sqlplus and connect to the readdb
2. run the read query, get status 'ACTIVE'
3. run the update query against the writedb in a different
   sqlplus
4. go back to the sqlplus from step (1), launch the read
   query from step (2) and get 'ACTIVE' again
5. repeat read query same
   as in step 4 -- get the correct 'DONE' response.

Comment: can you add an example of the two sessions?

Comment: You mean actual SQL?

Comment: The best would be a simple test case that can be reproduced on any system. At least statements and output of both sessions. But no data that compromises your system

Comment: @miracle173 I did what I could, pretty much everything short on the table schema.  I'll play with it tomorrow.

Comment: OK, I think I've made this perfect now.

Comment: What you described here does not conform to any transaction isolation level. The only way I could reproduce it was by enabling the Result Cache. For example with `result_cache_mode`set to `FORCE` and `result_cache_remote_expiration` set to `1`, the database caches results related to remote objects, and these results remain valid for `1` minute (or more, depending on the value of this parameter), so you can get stale results. By default these parameters are not set (`MANUAL` and `0`). I would check the values of these parameters and the `V$RESULT_CACHE_*` views for anything related.

Comment: Well, right, it doesn't make sense and yet we are seeing it!  The settings are MANUAL and 0; I am not sure what to look for in V$RESULT_CACHE_...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oracle has spoken:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14231/ds_txnman.htm#i1008473

> Distributed Query Returns Different Results on Consecutive Runs when
>   no Changes Exist in the Base Tables. (Doc ID 561471.1)

...skip some more writing...

> Bug.611416 SELECT AFTER UPDATE AND COMMIT DOESN'T SHOW UPDATED COLUMNS

...skip some more writing...

> "You can use the following techniques to ensure that the SCNs of the
>   two machines are synchronized just before a query:
>   * Because SCNs are synchronized at the end of a remote query, precede each remote query with a dummy remote query to the same site, for
>   example, SELECT * FROM DUAL@REMOTE.
>   * Because SCNs are synchronized at the start of every remote transaction, commit or roll back the current transaction before
>   issuing the remote query. "